# 3D remote desktops for CAD/CAM

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop, remote

Has anyone managed to present Ansys Workbench or Pro Engineer using Terminal Services (or any other 3D appplication) on W2K8 R2 server. I would be interested to hear your outcomes. We currently are looking at technology to enable to our users to use this software remotely.

TIA
Neil

Answer (score 2):

You have too look into [RemoteFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX) that ships with Windows 2008 R2 SP1, and optionally a GPU in your TS server and it should do the trick. In a LAN you can even do Crysis over RDP!

You also need to appropriately scale the number of CPUs+GPUs according to expected number of concurrent users and the latency shouldn't be too high of course.

As a sidenote: on Linux that is not a problem at all due to the slickness of `VirtualGL` and `TurboVNC`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible in theory, although I've never seen it done in practice.  Whether you'd get a decent user experience over a remote connection is a different question.  I think you might also run into vendor support issues.  Vendors of this stuff tend to be a bit picky about supported configurations.  In the first instance, I'd go to them and get them to provide a reference site with a configuration they're prepared to support.

As an alternative, you can get laptops with mobile quadro cards certified to run with most if not all major CAD applications.  They're a bit pricey, but well and truly lost in the noise compared to the cost per seat of any major CAD application.  At a guess, I'd say this will work better than attempts to run it over a remote connection.